# Date comparison is incorrect

Tags: vba, excel, date, date-comparison

This is just part of a vba code I am writing and simple date comparison is not working. I have one sheet with tons of data and the vba code creates a pivot table. The code runs fine and does filter out all the past dates but it does not filter out (Feb 3 and Feb 4) for some reason (today is Feb 29). It filters out all the other Feb dates properly but its just those two dates. Anyone know what is wrong?

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivottable1").PivotFields("issuedate")
    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        If pi < Date Then
            pi.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pi
End With
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask follow this to ask a question first

Comment: I once has a similar problem with dates coming from an SQL Server. The problem is that Excel does not understand the `datetime` fields coming from an SQL Server because it includes milliseconds. So the date format was `2015-02-04 00:00:00.000`. Excel cannot understand this. But if you change it to `2015-02-04 00:00:00` then it works. Could that be the problem?

Comment: you can also use the function `DateDiff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the column type is a date and not a string? Maybe try CDate(pi)?

If that doesn't work please post the dates that aren't working - maybe by doing a Debug.print(pi).

Comment: `Typename(Pi)`must be `date`. Also, don't use variables with confusing names like Pi , wich should already be 3.1415 but strangely isn't...